# Is the SARS-CoV-2 that causes COVID-19 the only known virus that enters the cells via the ACE2 receptors?

Tags: covid-19, infectious-diseases, sars-cov-2, ace2

I am just curious if the virus is unique in the sense that it enters the ACE2 receptors in the human body and kills the cell. This receptor is located over the entire body.

Is this the only virus in existance to have this feature?

Comment: What has your prior research revealed?

Comment: @Carey. My prior research seem to suggest that this feature is somewhat of a novelty.but then you see I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** In addition to the COVID-19 causing SARS-CoV-2 virus there's the related SARS-CoV-1 virus (colloquially known as just "SARS") that was the driver of the [outbreak in 2002-04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002%E2%80%932004_SARS_outbreak), and there's [NL63-CoV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_coronavirus_NL63).

Comment: Ok but they both belong to the group of *Coronaviridae* and are closely related. Are there a bit more unrelated viruses who use the ACE2R as entrance pathway?